# How do I update a specific value within array in a products metadata?

Tags: post-meta

Im trying to update a products meta information with values from a calculation.

Back story is that we are selling parking spaces for an airport and the current system we have in place is that a parking product has 31 variations, the user would put in a date and time for entry to exit and it would calculate a price depending on how many days they stopped etc.

Currently we have to do a calculation on a settings page and then manually copy across the values to the product variations, which is tedious if we wanted a quick price change.

So I googled and found out get_post_meta() and was able to pull all the info I needed regarding the 31 variations.

```
 $product_attr = get_post_meta( 148 , 'redq_day_ranges_cost');
 print_r($product_attr[0]);
```

Which got my halfway there the result were as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 1
                [max_days] => 1
                [range_cost] => 29.5
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 2
                [max_days] => 2
                [range_cost] => 17.25
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 3
                [max_days] => 3
                [range_cost] => 13.1667
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 4
                [max_days] => 4
                [range_cost] => 11.125
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 5
                [max_days] => 5
                [range_cost] => 9.9
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 6
                [max_days] => 6
                [range_cost] => 9.0833
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 7
                [max_days] => 7
                [range_cost] => 8.5
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 8
                [max_days] => 8
                [range_cost] => 8.0625
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 9
                [max_days] => 9
                [range_cost] => 7.7222
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 10
                [max_days] => 10
                [range_cost] => 7.45
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 11
                [max_days] => 11
                [range_cost] => 7.2273
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 12
                [max_days] => 12
                [range_cost] => 7.0417
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 13
                [max_days] => 13
                [range_cost] => 6.8846
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 14
                [max_days] => 14
                [range_cost] => 6.75
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 15
                [max_days] => 15
                [range_cost] => 6.6333
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 16
                [max_days] => 16
                [range_cost] => 6.5313
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 17
                [max_days] => 17
                [range_cost] => 6.4412
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 18
                [max_days] => 18
                [range_cost] => 6.3611
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 19
                [max_days] => 19
                [range_cost] => 6.2895
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 20
                [max_days] => 20
                [range_cost] => 6.225
            )

        [20] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 21
                [max_days] => 21
                [range_cost] => 6.1667
            )

        [21] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 22
                [max_days] => 22
                [range_cost] => 6.1136
            )

        [22] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 23
                [max_days] => 23
                [range_cost] => 6.0652
            )

        [23] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 24
                [max_days] => 24
                [range_cost] => 6.0208
            )

        [24] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 25
                [max_days] => 25
                [range_cost] => 5.98
            )

        [25] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 26
                [max_days] => 26
                [range_cost] => 5.9423
            )

        [26] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 27
                [max_days] => 27
                [range_cost] => 5.9074
            )

        [27] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 28
                [max_days] => 28
                [range_cost] => 5.875
            )

        [28] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 29
                [max_days] => 29
                [range_cost] => 5.8448
            )

        [29] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 30
                [max_days] => 30
                [range_cost] => 5.8167
            )

        [30] => Array
            (
                [min_days] => 31
                [max_days] => 31
                [range_cost] => 5.7903
            )

    )

)
```

But now how would do I go about updating the range_cost for each one.

Im guessing it would be something along the lines of

```
$newcosts = array(
   [0][0][range_cost] => 30,
   [0][1][range_cost] => 29,
);
update_post_meta(148, 'redq_day_ranges_cost', $newcosts);
```

But Im not sure any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit off-topic, but nevertheless...

Let's say you want to change first range_cost to 5.789 and third to 6.890 for product 148. Here's the code:

```
$product_attr = get_post_meta( 148 , 'redq_day_ranges_cost');
$product_attr[0][0]['range_cost'] = 5.789;
$product_attr[0][2]['range_cost'] = 6.890;
update_post_meta(148, 'redq_day_ranges_cost', $product_attr);
```